# Source file exists on a broken HDD, can't uninstall program

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Currently I'm trying to install a program I used a long time ago. It's a newer version of the old program. The problem lies with the previous install. I installed it on an external HDD that no longer works. There are some residual files on my internal store--enough that the computer recognizes the program as having been "installed"; however, because the *source file* only existed on the external (I was like 14 when I last used that HD, and an irresponsible user, at that), I can't modify/uninstall/repair the old version. Now when I try to install the new version, I get an error reading along the lines of "Make sure the source file exists and that you can access it."

So what do I do if the source file doesn't exist, and I can't access it?

tl;dr: source file is stored on a broken HDD, can't uninstall program from my internal HDD or install new version of broken program

Comment: You can forcibly uninstall applications without the source files. Please search for forced uninstall on Windows. This has been a capability for a long time using mature apps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the “Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter” and follow the prompts to fix the issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

I recommend starting by choosing the option that you can not uninstall a program.

Comment: A Microsoft Troubleshooting tool that actually worked! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results from using the registry cleaner in CCleaner to purge all "useless" registry entries. Of course, when the program suggests to back up the registry, it's wise to do so. Add another layer of protection by creating a restore point prior to these operations.

Also, I've had to run the registry clean sequence multiple times to get all the dead wood out.

That will usually remove remnants of broken software. It's also a good idea to search for file folders that contain the program name in advance.

Comment: Registry cleaners have a high likelihood of causing unintended problems, and they will not address the files left behind.

Comment: Over the past 18 years, I've had success with the recommendation I've posted. Manually locating files addresses the files left behind. CCleaner registry cleaner has caused me zero problems. I can't respond regarding other products.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used a utility called Revo Uninstaller to forcibly remove the files and registry entries a bad Uninstaller cannot remove.

A nice feature of this tool is that it tries to create a Restore Point before each process, and you can backup the registry files it will remove before removing them, making it easy to recover if you remove something incorrectly.